# Having a hard time creating MYSQL table/defining fields using the syntax

Tags: mysql, sql

Trying to create a table and define the fields, but having a hard time doing this because I can never seem to get the syntax correct.

I've tried as many different formats of the code as possible. I've done it with/without parenthesis, commas, single quotation marks, etc. I've changed the spacing as well. I have never actually been successful in creating the table. I have made sure I am in a database. Every internet resource I've been trying to use looks different and is using a different MySQL program and they are never set up the same, so it's confused me and nothing I've tried has been right even though I'm trying what's been done by others.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE students(
    -> student_id PRIMARY KEY, AUTO_INCREMENT,
    -> name VARCHAR(20),
    -> sex ENUM('M', 'F')
    -> );
```

I expected I would have a Query OK message but I've only ever gotten this: 
    ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the 
    manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax 
    to use 
    near 'PRIMARY KEY, AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(20),
    sex ENUM('M', 'F')
    )' at line 2

Comment: A) Names are often a *lot* longer than 20 characters. Use `VARCHAR(255)` as a default string-type field. B) That's not how "sex" works. If anything that should be "gender", but ask yourself, does that matter? Too many forms are far too intrusive, collecting information of dubious utility.

Answer (score 1):

Attributes are separated by spaces, not commas, and you also need to specify the type, so:

```
student_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked. This is also just for a school assignment(I just started) so I'm doing it how they want it.

Comment: Indeed. Well, hope your assignment goes well.

Comment: As a note, if you ever need help with the syntax, tools like [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) help considerably.